# My nav-bar wont center completely - only a little?

Tags: css, center, navbar

I have a problem with my navbar. I centered it using CSS but not completely, it is a little bit to the right.

[image]

As you can see it is not centered completely in the middle as it should be.

My CSS:

```
.nav {
    border: none;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav li {
    display:inline;
}
.nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px:
    color: black;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;    
}
```

I think it is because I have the word PORTFOLIO which is longer, but how can I move INDEX and ABOUT a little to the left then?

Comment: you need to add your html and css. this code does not replicate your problem

Comment: Just add a fix width to your nav and center it then.

Comment: Assuming the list items are wrapped within an `<ul>` element which is unstyled, I've posted my suggestion below.

Answer (score 3):

`<ul>` elements natively have offset margin. You can reset it with:

```
.nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```